# How to keep variable value throughout request

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm creating REST service where I will expect specific "ticket" to be passed every request. This way I don't have to create sessions (and my clients can't support them).

I want to store this ticket somewhere until request completes. I will call methods and they will call other methods, connections, etc - I just want this data to be available from code anywhere during this request.

I know static class/variable won't work since it's application-wide.

What my choices are?

**EDIT:** 
Basically, I want some kind of storage "bag" that I can populate in my webservice method and that will be accessible from any place in app. And this need to live only for length of this request.

Comment: You asking about the server, client, or both? I think we need a separation of the details for each.

Comment: Server only. I don't care about clients. So, I get call and it has some "ticket". I want to preserve this data so it will be shared on server side for duration of this call only.

Comment: What about a cookieless session?

Comment: Cookieless session is what? Keeping in URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask is generally bad practice. If you need some data in any method you should get them either as parameter or as instance data (object where you call the method).

Anyway if you write REST service you most proabably use AspNetCompatibility mode. In such case you should have access to `HttpContext.Current.Items`. If you don't use `AspNetCompatibility` mode you can create your [own extension for OperationContext](http://blog.caraulean.com/2008/02/13/httpcontext-idiom-for-windows-communication-foundation/).

Comment: Here is more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409170/saas-with-database-per-client-single-point-for-entry-for-services-performance

Comment: So, I want to know WHICH database to connect to. And I don't want to pass around Application Id on every call. Is that bad practice? Otherwise each constructor will have to be overriden. For example I have my own MembershipProvider and there is no way to pass data into it since methods executed via built-in Membership. I'd like to know inside my provider WHICH db to talk to.

Comment: Yes, HttpContext will work for me. If you can elaborate why this is bad practice I will appreciate it :)

Comment: Yes it is still bad practice. Once you start using some global per request object you will still have to maintain it in either of two mentioned contexts. This will make all your code dependent on static property in `HttpContext` or `OperationContext`. Reusability = 0, Testability = 0. What I described is called dependency injection and it can be partially automated by some APIs.

Comment: I'm just starting so I'd like to do is as "correct" as possible. Problem here is connection string. SInce same app will connect to different databases depending on Customer - I have to do something. Usually - I would just have it in WebConfig. Now I have to get conn string from System database depending on who connects. What Automated APIs can I use to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Use a database as storage 'bag'.

Any other kind of global place to store data (file?) will do but be aware of locking when multiples thread try to access this resource at the same time.

Comment: Database won't work. For example, I need to store "AuthTicket". If I store it like that - how do I know which client have which one? Same situation.